# Webpack SSR configuration

Tags: symfony, webpack, server-side, client-side

I have two configuration files for webpack one for the server-side and the other for the client-side on my Symfony project, my questions are how to disable exporting the images for the server-side and use the images that got exported for the client-side?
Another question how to ignore dynamic imports from being bundled in separate files?

Answer (score 0):

For the images:

```
.addRule({
    test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg|webp)$/,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
        name: '[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
        emitFile: false,
        publicPath: '/build/images'
    }
})
```

For the dynamic imports, I did it like that but I couldn't ignore the export of this file:

```
.configureSplitChunks(function (splitChunks) {
    splitChunks.cacheGroups = {
        chunks: 'async',
        async: {
            name: 'dynamicImports',
            maxSize: Infinity
        }
    };
})
```